# How can I copy Scala.js source maps using resourceGenerators?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

I'm using `resourceGenerators` sbt key to copy `fastOptJs`-generated .js files when using `products`, like this:

```
(resourceGenerators in Compile) <+=
        (fastOptJS in Compile in frontend, packageScalaJSLauncher in Compile in frontend, packageJSDependencies in Compile in frontend)
          .map((f1, f2, f3) => {
            Seq(f1.data, f2.data, f3)
          })
```

Running the following in sbt, I can see the path of generated file:

```
> show frontend/fastOptJS
[info] Attributed(/some/path/frontend/target/scala-2.11/frontend-fastopt.js)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 12, 2016 1:59:22 PM
```

Similarly, I can easily see where Scala.js-generated launcher ends up:

```
> show frontend/packageScalaJSLauncher
[info] Attributed(/some/path/frontend/target/scala-2.11/frontend-launcher.js)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 12, 2016 2:00:10 PM
```

I cannot, however, find a task/key that would point me to location of `.js.map` file. I tried looking in the plugin sources, but couldn't find it. Is there any way of doing that without resorting to creating a manual mapping in `build.sbt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source maps generated by Scala.js always have the name of the corresponding .js file `+ ".map"`. So you can find the one associated with `f1` with `f1.getParentFile / (f1.getName + ".map")`.

Btw, no new build should use `<+=`. The more understandable `+=` should be used instead:

```
resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val f1 = (fastOptJS in Compile in frontend).value.data
  val f1SourceMap = f1.getParentFile / (f1.getName + ".map")
  val f2 = (packageScalaJSLauncher in Compile in frontend).value.data
  val f3 = (packageJSDependencies in Compile in frontend).value
  Seq(f1, f1SourceMap, f2, f3)
}
```

and to avoid the `in Compile` everywhere, you can use `inConfig(Compile)`:

```
inConfig(Compile)(Seq(
  resourceGenerators += Def.task {
    val f1 = (fastOptJS in frontend).value.data
    val f1SourceMap = f1.getParentFile / (f1.getName + ".map")
    val f2 = (packageScalaJSLauncher in frontend).value.data
    val f3 = (packageJSDependencies in frontend).value
    Seq(f1, f1SourceMap, f2, f3)
  }
))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Still, I feel it'd be safer if plugin could provide that location as a sbt key, instead of fiddling with paths.

Comment: Feel free to [file a feature request](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues).